# Spring integrated TCP client - Not sending multiple messages Intermittent issue

Tags: java, spring-integration

Currently, we are using Spring Integration 2.1.0 Release in our application. Application flow is as below:

1) The application process some data and put the final string on Active MQ.

2) I have used message-driven-channel-adapter and service-activator to read the data from the queue.

3) That data is displayed successfully on Server(application is working as a client) using tcp-outbound-gateway.

4) I am using single-use="true", as the requirement is to disconnect the channel on acknowledgment or after the timeout.

5) Problem is when data is in bulk, let's say there is 10 message in the queue so it will show connect and disconnect 10 times instead of sending requestMessage on the connection.

Looks like it is due to threading used by spring, as when I have applied breakpoint on handleMessageInternal(Message) method of TcpOutboundGateway, every message is sending successfully, when control reaches at connection.send(requestMessage);  but with the run mode I am seeing connect, disconnect behavior without the incoming message.

Code for configuration is

```
<int:channel id="telnetChannel" />
<beans:bean id="clientCustomSerializer"
class="com.telnet.core.serializer.CustomSerializer">
<beans:property name="terminatingChar" value="10" />
<beans:property name="maxLength" value="65535" />
</beans:bean>
<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface="com.telnet.core.integration.connection.ParseConfig$SimpleGateway"
default-request-channel="telnetClientChannel"/>

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="clientFactory"
type="client" host="localhost" port="1122" single-use="true" using-nio="false" serializer="${client.serializer}" deserializer="${client.serializer}" so-timeout="10000"
/>
<ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="clientInGwAck" request-channel="telnetChannel"
connection-factory="clientFactory"
reply-channel="replyChannel"
reply-timeout="10000"/>


<!-- To send the messege over server via JMS and serviceActivator -->
<int:channel id="requestMessageChannel" />
<beans:bean id="clientServiceActivator" class= 
"com.telnet.core.integration.clientServiceActivator">
</beans:bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="requestMessageChannelAdapter" 
error-channel="errorChannel"
connection-factory="mqConnectionFactory"
destination-name="${client.messaging.processing.queues}" 
channel="requestMessageChannel"/>

<int:service-activator id="messageActivator" 
input-channel="requestMessageChannel" 
output-channel="telnetChannel"
ref="clientServiceActivator" method="getOutboundMessage">
</int:service-activator>
```

Here the problem is if there are multiple message so it is showing connected and disconnected without any data stream. Looks like it is due to threading implemented by spring. Assistance required how to fix this issue.

Comment: You're using `single-use` and you're wondering why it is single-use?

Comment: What is the question though? And what is that "run mode", too?

Comment: Ideal behavior with single-use is, it should connect the channel post that send the message stream after that disconnect either post getting acknowledgement or post so-timeout. But it is just showing connected and disconnected, without any data stream.

Comment: For debugging we use breakpoint in STS , and if i use break point in TcpOutboundGateway.handleMessageInternal(Message) so it is showing data stream on channel but if i skip that breakpoints(i.e. run mode) so not getting any messages.

Comment: Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: This issue is still not resolved, please provide assistance. Gary request you to provide some pointers.